# Linear derivative of nonlinear odd function possible?

Tags: derivatives

Can the derivative of an odd , non-linear function ever be linear?
Need a mathematical proof or example of if being linear.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Consider what type of functions can have linear derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

The only functions which derive to a linear function are their anti-derivatives:

$$\int(ax+b)dx = {1 \over 2}ax^2 + bx + C $$

They are all quadratic polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

While in general only functions of degree two have linear derivatives, this idea comes from the implication that the ring the polynomial comes from is an integral domain, such as $R[x]$.. If the ring is not an integral domain, there can be an odd function whose derivative is a linear function.

$$2x^3+x^2+x\in Z_6 [x]$$
$$\frac {d}{dx} (2x^3+x^2+x) = 2x+1$$

Comment: Why is $2x^3+x^2+x$ an odd function? I think a good example is $2x^3+x\in\mathcal{Z}_6[x]$.